# Pass Data from an activity to launcher activity

Tags: android

I want to pass data from an activity to launcher activity without actually opening the sender activity *i.e.*

**without visiting the sender activity , I want some data to be passed into launcher activity as soon as I open my app** .

Is it possible??

Thanks.

Comment: Use `Shared Preferences`

Comment: Can you explain what is sender and launcher activity?

Comment: By sender activity , i mean second(2nd) activity and my launcher activity is obviously the first one .What i want is as soon as I open my app, data fetched from second activity to launcher activity and should be visible to the user without visiting to second activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a way to do this

Here's an example

**Sender Activity**

```
public class PlayerScreen extends Activity{

   static PlayerScreen playerScreen;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.player);
        playerScreen = this;
   }

   public void update(){
      .
      .
      .
   }

   public static PlayerScreen getInstance() {
        return playerScreen;
   }

}
```

**LauncherActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle){

        super.onCreate(bundle);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        try{
             PlayerScreen.getInstance().update();
        } catch(Exception e){

        }finally{

       }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you wanna pass some data, I don't think you need an sender activity. If you have many things to do, Service is a better choice.

Comment: This should be a comment. Not an Answer.

Comment: @ChiragSavsani What I can do is to give some general suggestion. I got too few things from the description.

Answer (score 0):

you can send a BroadCast when you start your app,like this

```
Intent intent = new Intent("your broadcast key");    
intent.putExtra(COUNTER_VALUE, counter);    
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

so you can receive it wherever you regist BroadCastReceiver to recerve the BroadCast.
like this

```
public void registerReceiver(Context ctx) {
    IntentFilter connFilter = new IntentFilter("your broadcast key");
    ctx.registerReceiver(instance, connFilter);
}

public void unregisterReceiver(Context ctx) {
    ctx.unregisterReceiver(instance);
    instance = null;
}

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    //do things here when you receive your broadcast
}
```

Comment: I Cannot use intent here . As i want that my app should read data from 2nd Activity and is visible to user as soon as the main activity is launched.

Comment: @JatinKhattar maybe you can jump to launcher activity as soon as your sender activity is oncreate,like this`@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        startActivity(new Intent(this,LauncherActivity.class));
    }` the sender activity will not visiable